# How to create a table tracking successively changing values of controls in Manipulate[...]

Tags: manipulate, code-request, output-formatting

Consider the following `code` that generates the desired output for a single vector of parameters (i.e., values of the controls). My purpose is to generate a set of vectors by fixing `x` and `y` while successively changing `z`, and repeating the same procedure for other parameters like fixing `x` and `z` while successively changing `y` and so on.

I like to create a table of successive iterations and record individual vectors of parameters and the associated functional values.

```
 f[x_, y_, z_] := x y + z^2 + y z;

 Manipulate[
    outputs= {{f[x, y, z], f[x, y, z]^2, f[x, y, z]^3}};
    TableForm[
        Map[If[NumericQ[#], If[# < 1 , Floor@#, Round[#, .1]], #] &, outputs, {-1}],
        TableHeadings -> {{{"x=" <> ToString[x], "y=" <> ToString[y],"z=" <> ToString[z]}}, {"Output 1", "Output 2", "Output 3"}}, 
        TableAlignments -> Right
             ],
  {x, 1, 20, 1},
  {y, 1, 20, 1},
  {z, .1, 1, .05}
 ]
```

An example table to be created looks like:

[image]

As is seen from the above table, I keep `x` and `y` variables fixed but `z` changes.

I like to create the above table using `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ClearAll[g, f, x, y, z, inputlist]

f[x_, y_, z_] := x y + z^2 + y z;

g[{x_, y_, z_}] := {f[x, y, z], f[x, y, z]^2, f[x, y, z]^3}
```

Using a smaller range for the three variables:

```
ranges = {xrange, yrange, zrange} = {Range[3], Range[3], Range[2, 4] .05};
```

Take 2-subsets of `ranges` form pairs for each subset:

```
tuples = Tuples /@ (Reverse /@ Subsets[Reverse@{xrange, yrange, zrange}, {2}]);
```

Use `tuples` to define a function that creates the desired input lists for `g`:

```
inputlist[x_, y_, z_] := Join @@ MapIndexed[
  Insert[tuples[[#2[[1]]]], #, Thread[{Range[Length@tuples[[#2[[1]]]]], #2[[1]]}]] &, 
  {x, y, z}];
```

Use with `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[TableForm[Map[If[NumericQ[#], If[# < 1, Floor@#, Round[#, .1]], #] &, 
     g /@ inputlist[x, y, z], {-1}], 
   TableHeadings -> {({"x=" <> ToString[#], "y=" <> ToString[#2], 
        "z=" <> ToString[#3]} & @@@ inputlist[x, y, z]),
     {"Output 1",  "Output 2", "Output 3"}}, 
   TableAlignments -> Right], 
 {x, xrange, Slider},
 {y, yrange, Slider}, 
 {z, zrange, Slider}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer because it does not have the flexibility of choosing a specific set of parameter values. It simply gives us sets of outputs:

```
 f[x_, y_, z_] := x y + z^2 + y z;

 Manipulate[
  outputs=Flatten[Table[{x, y, z, f[x, y, z], f[x, y, z]^2,f[x, y, z]^3},{x,1,5,1}, {y,1,5,1}, {z,.1,1,.1}], 1];
  TableForm[
     Map[If[NumericQ[#], If[# < 0 , Floor@#, Round[#, .1]], #] &, outputs[[n]],{-1}], 
     TableHeadings -> {None, {"x","y","z","output 1","output 2","output 3"}}, 
     TableAlignments -> Right
            ],
  {n, 1, Length[outputs], 1}
 ]
```